# Hide Objects with negative coordinates adobe flash

Tags: flash, object, adobe, hide, frame

I designing a banner in Adobe Flash Professional and i'm using Motion Tween to move out an image of the "visible" area with negative cordinates.

But if i enlarge the flash player frame i see the image that is supposed to be hidden.

How i manage to hide an image?

Thank you

Comment: http://imgur.com/HqCwxQi

it's a simple up and down images

Comment: I was asking for the method that you tried.

Comment: i moved the image with motion tween to negative coordinates. when i visualize with the html page the html code crop the .swf and the negative coordinates "don't exist" but if i open the .swf the flash player, it renders the negative coordinates revealing the "hidden" images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask layer of rectangular shape.
In flash editor 
1) Create new layer
2) Draw a rectangle on that layer which matches the stage size
3) Right-click on the title of the layer and select "Mask" in drop-down menu
4) Drag the layer with your image right under the "Mask" layer. You should see that the layer became masked (the icon of the layer will change its view, and its icon+title will shift a little right).